# TDD with Yii and captcha

Tags: php, yii, tdd, phpunit

I have a problem with test my model for validation.

I want to test some validation (password compare, required fields and etc).

But I cant! I have a problem witch captcha. How can I solve it?

How to pass captcha for success test?

Comment: The question is ambiguous.. what is the problem exactly that you are facing?? Is the captcha not getting generated? ? Or os it not getting validated? ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you exact code, but hopefully this will put you in the right direction.  And the following answer is for Yii's built-in captcha, and not a third-party plugin/api

First, a captcha is stored in the session data, meaning you can access it directly if you know the correct variable name.

Second, rather than testing captcha, you may just want to "mock" captcha.  Yii was built on TDD and therefore tested the components that you are using.  You don't need to retest captcha and make sure it sets the session variable, because Yii already did that and their tests show that it works.

What I would do, figure out which session variable is set by captcha, manually set that variable to a dummy text (`abcdefg`), then fill out your model and captcha field/variable with the same dummy text (`abcdefg`) and then you can test validating and failing the captcha field.

My other option would be to manually a captcha, (create/generate, but not render) so that the text is set, then use `CCaptchaAction`'s method `getVerifyCode()` to get the code that is to be verified.  I believe that method also generates a captcha text and saves it in the session as well if it doesn't exist.